# Best Tools to Generate Visual UML Diagrams for Python

Tags: python, diagram

I've done some class diagramming with erdantic. It's pretty limited but it's pretty easy to access and diagram out classes quickly in .png form.

However, I'm looking for something higher level, so I can diagram an entire module. I looked into doxygen's ability to diagram but I think its limited to C++ according to the documentation I read (and linked above).

Is there any other standard tool that can do this?

** p.s. yes I tried pycharm which is handy for class diagrams, but I'm really looking at something that can diagram from the modular level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `pyreverse`. It's installed as part of the [pylint](https://pypi.org/project/pylint/) package so it's possible you already have it. Someone else already beat me to a pyreverse explainer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36432630/class-diagram-viewer-application-for-python3-source

Answer (score 0):

The title of the question said UML diagrams, so let me suggest VisualParadigm, which has a free version community edition.  It is highly capable with some project management.  It is bidirectional for Java.  Because it has many capacities, it can be hard to learn, but I've found I can use the diagramming features and ignore those I don't need.